# Laravel - How to register a new user using the AuthController that Laravel provides in another controller

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

So I am building a checkout functionality. If the user is a guest he could use his credentials to make a new registration with the order he makes. I have used the auth scaffold Laravel provides with the command `php artisan make:auth`. I have an OrdersController and the AuthController that comes with the framework. How can I register a new user within my OrdersController? Here is my code:
 checkout.blade.php:

```
<li class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <h4>Register</h4>

    <input id="create-act" type="checkbox" class="input-chkbox" name="register">
    <label for="create-act">Create user account?</label>
</li>
<li class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 create-account">

    <label for="password">Password<em>*</em></label>
    <input required type="text" class="input-text" id="password"
           name="password">
</li>
<li class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 create-account">
    <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password<em>*</em></label>
    <input required type="text" class="input-text"
           id="password_confirmation"
           name="password_confirmation">
</li>
```

OrdersController inside addOrder method:

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
 $this->validate($request, [
        'password' => 'required|password',
        'confirm_password' => 'required|'
    ]);
}
```

I want to register the new user inside this if. How can I do that?

Edit: Here is my protected function create inside my AuthController.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $confirmationCode = str_random(30);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'confirmation_code' => $confirmationCode
    ]);

    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Customer')->first());
    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->user_id = $user->id;
    $cart->save();
    if(Session::has('cartItems')) {
        foreach (Session::get('cartItems') as $sessionCartItem) {
            $cartItem = new CartItem();
            $cartItem->product_id = $sessionCartItem['product']->id;
            $cartItem->cart_id = $cart->id;
            $cartItem->size = $sessionCartItem['size'];
            $cartItem->quantity = $sessionCartItem['quantity'];
            $cartItem->save();
        }
    }

    Session::flush();
    $cart->save();

    $email = $user['email'];
    $name = $user['name'];

    Mail::send('auth.emails.user-confirmation', ['name' => $name, 'confirmation_code' => $user['confirmation_code']], function ($message) use ($email, $name) {
        $message->from('mymail@gmail.com', 'Name Family')->to($email, $name)->subject('Confirm email');
    });

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Why re-implement this? Why not use the existing controller which already registers users and just change the redirect to your checkout?

Comment: Because I need to be able to register users inside my register page as well.

Comment: You don't have to permanently change the default redirect. Only if the reg request is coming from a checkout.

Comment: @apokryfos My register method needs a Request $request to work. I get the request for my addOrder method and I need to pass that $request to the redirect. How can I do that?

Comment: Actually since you've updated the question, it's probably far easier to make the `create` function in the AuthController `public static` and call it from the `OrderController`. Of course it's even better if you move this to a library instead of having it as a controller method (since it is more business logic than it is controller logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want my OrdersController to extend my AuthController, was to lazy to extract the authentication logic into a library and just redirecting if the register checkbox was checked didn't work. I just decided to duplicate part of my registration logic inside my OrdersController. It is not good practice for sure, but it is a workaround until I extract the login into a library. Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $this->validate($request, [
       'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
       'password_confirmation' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),
        'phone_number' => $request['phone']
    ]); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you can easily create user with the request:

```
$user = User::create($request->all());
```

Make sur that the `$request` variable matches the columns of `users` table.

**EDIT**: To call a function from another controller:

```
class OrdersController extends AuthController
{
    ...
    $this->create(...);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Check my create method inside my AuthController. There I attach roles and send a confirmation email. How can I access that method from my OrdersController, rather than using User::create($data)?

Comment: @Codearts just extends the AuthController and you can call the function create. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

After you validation succeeds
Fetch out all the data from $request that you need for you user table,
use the User model to insert a column,

you can use

```
$user=User::create($dataObject);
```

or you can use

```
$user=User::insert([
'username'=>$request->username,
'password'=>Hash::make($request->password)
]);
```

Than you can use the Auth Guard method to login the user

```
Auth::login($user);
return;
```

**Edit** : Create a library function and use it where ever you want

```
<?php

namespace App\Lib\User;

class Creator
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
       // do what you want
      // return what you want
    }
}
```

Than use this function in order controller or auth controller

```
use App\Lib\User\Creator;

 public function __construct(Creator $creator) {
        $this->creator=$creator;
    }
 public function register(){
  $user=$this->creator->create($data);
 }
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Check my create method inside my AuthController. There I attach roles and send a confirmation email. How can I access that method from my OrdersController, rather than using User::create($data)?

Comment: You can not use a protected function of a class in to other unless you extend it,

instead of using the same function of controller

create a seperate class in a different folder ,
use that class in both order controller and auth controller

The way i have done in my application is that i have a librar folder inside the app folder in that i have user folder and in that i have to files creator.php and updator.php

creator.php consists of a class and a function to create a user, i just use this class in any controller and call this function

Answer (score 1):

The AuthController does a simple `User::create($data);` **after** the validation is done. Optionally you could do `Auth::guard()->login($user);` which will automatically login the newly created user.

Comment: I have updated my question. Check my create method inside my AuthController. There I attach roles and send a confirmation email. How can I access that method from my OrdersController, rather than using User::create($data)?